# Is it possible to view a history of commits to all branches of remote?

Tags: git

I have a remote repository in git. Inside it, I have many branches which contain several commits.

Is it possible to print history of all commits of the remote? So I can see commits to all branches?

Comment: Did you try googling?  [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
// Updates the cache of remote repositories
> git fetch

// Logs your remote branches' commits
> git log --all --oneline <origin/yourbranch>
```

Comment: I need log of all branches that belong to remote. Not particular branch

Comment: @AlexeyK the answer takes it into account